# NodeJS callback - Access to 'res'

Tags: node.js, callback, closures

I am using the Express framework and I have the following in one of my route files:

```
var allUsersFromDynamoDb = function (req, res) {
var dynamodbDoc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var params = {
    TableName: "users",
    ProjectionExpression: "username,loc,age"
};

dynamodbDoc.scan(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err));
        res.statusCode = 500;
        res.send("Internal Server Error");
    } else {
        console.log("DynamoDB Query succeeded.");
        res.end(JSON.stringify(data.Items));
    }
});
}
```

I am using the above function in one of my routes:

```
router.get('/users', allUsersFromDynamoDb);
```

Now the callback that I am defining while making a call to the "scan" on dynamodbDoc can be pretty useful if defined as a separate function. I can re-use that for some of my other routes as well.

But how can I can still get access to the "res" inside this new function?

I think I should be using "closure" but I can't seem to get it exactly right. I think I would need to maintain the signature of the new callback function to expect 2 params, "err" and "data" as per the following page:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#scan-property

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: I think you can place the callback into it's own named function as long it is in the same scope from where `dynamodbDoc.scan` is being called. Here, due to the `closure` feature of JS, your callback will have access to the same `res` object as `dynamodbDoc.scan`.

Comment: Oh yes, that's an option. I should have actually mentioned that in my question description. But if I do that then that callback function won't be available outside 'allUserFromDynamoDB' function. Let's say I had another function (for a different route) 'getSpecificUserFromDynamoDB' from where I wanted to use it too. Hope it's clear what I'm saying.

Comment: Trouble is that if the callback function is defined outside the scope of `allUsersFromDynamoDb`, then it won't have access to `res` or req` objects. You _can_ find a workaround I think (depending on the specific use).

Answer (score 2):

You can use that function as middleware of every routes you want http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

The new route with the middleware:

```
var middlewares = require('./middlewares'),
    controllers = require('./controllers');

router.get('/users', middlewares.allUsersFromDynamoDb, controllers.theRouteController);
```

The middleware (`middlewares.js`) where you pass your data to `req` so you can use that data everywhere you have `req`:

```
exports.allUsersFromDynamoDb = function (req, res, next) {
    var dynamodbDoc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    var params = {
        TableName: "users",
        ProjectionExpression: "username,loc,age"
    };

    dynamodbDoc.scan(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err));
            next("Internal Server Error");
        } else {
            console.log("DynamoDB Query succeeded.");
            req.dataScan = JSON.stringify(data.Items);
            next();
        }
    });
};
```

And finally the controller (`controllers.js`):

```
exports.theRouteController = function (req, res) {
    // Here is the dataScan you defined in the middleware
    res.jsonp(req.dataScan);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Michelem! What I was really hoping to do was to reuse most of the code for "function(err, data)", so I don't have to repeat it for other routes I have. I did something based on your suggestion of using a middleware which made things a bit cleaner. I'll post what I did here as a different answer as the space in a comment is limited.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Michelem's answer here I tried something which makes things a bit cleaner and code more reusable:

```
var allUsersFromDynamoDb = function (req, res, next) {
var dynamodbDoc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var params = {
    TableName: "users",
    ProjectionExpression: "username,loc,age"
};

dynamodbDoc.scan(params, function (err, data) {
    req.err = err;
    req.data = data;
    next();
});
}
```

Now I declare another function:

```
var processUserResults = function (req, res, next) {
if (req.err) {
    console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(req.err));
    res.statusCode = 500;
    res.send("Internal Server Error");
} else {
    console.log("DynamoDB Query succeeded.");
    res.end(JSON.stringify(req.data.Items));
}
};
```

And finally this:

```
router.get('/users', [allUsersFromDynamoDb, processUserResults]);
```

All I need to do in the original "function(err, data)" callback is always set 2 values:

```
req.err = err
req.data = data
```

And call next(). And processUserResults can similarly be used for other routes.

Still curious to find out if there are any other efficient solutions.